# loop arraylist of array in java

Tags: java, string, for-loop, arraylist, foreach

- I want to loop trough an arraylist of String arrays.
- These string arrays have only two elements. inside the loop i would like to compare these two elements of each array.
- i would like to do this in a clean and simple way (avoiding classic for, iterator class, etc., if possible -i know how to do this those ways, but I'm looking for a cleaner way-.
- i would prefer a for-each loop (or for + ":")
- I'm attaching a sample code to show you what i want to do.

what is the best way for doing this?

```
ArrayList<String[]> myLst = new ArrayList<String[]>();

// the array of strings has two elements

public String getSecondField(String query)
{
    for (String[] binArray : myLst)
    {
        if (binArray[0].equals(query))
        {
            return binArray[1];
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Why not just a `Map<String, String>`?

Comment: i like your aproach very much. i will possibly stick to it if no better solutions are posted :)

Comment: Please stop editing "i" into questions. There is literally no situation in which "i" appears by itself uncapitalized in English; if you're going to edit posts to fix their grammar, please do so correctly. When referring to yourself, "I" is *always* capitalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of arrays of two elements, and since all the first elements of each array are unique, use a `Map<String, String>`. This way, your code will become:

```
public String getSecondField(String query)
{
    String ret = map.get(query);
    return ret != null ? ret : "";
}
```

Comment: i also need to retrieve the index sometimes, like this:  public int obtenerPosPaises(String palabra)
 {
  int i = 0;
     for (String[] pais : mtxPaises)
     {
      if (pais[1].equals(palabra)) {
       return i;
      }
      i++;
     }
     return -1;
 }

Comment: Use a `LinkedHashMap` then, it guarantees insertion order, and iterate over the map's `.values()`

Comment: very clean, thanks a lot !